# Ordered Probit with Simulation Data in R

Tags: r, metrics, montecarlo, categorical-data

this is my first question asked in StackExchange. I am a big fan and use the many versions to learn LaTex, R, etc. I tried searching for a previous question, and while there are some similar ones, there's nothing conclusive with respect to my question. I appreciate any help offered.

I am conducting a Monte Carlo and examining how different discrete estimation procedures, namely tobit, probit, multinomial logic, and ordered probit, compare.

Here's how I'm generating the data:

```
x_1 <- replicate(100, rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 2))
x_2 <- replicate(100, rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd = 2))
error <- replicate(100, rnorm(500, mean = 0, sd= 1 ))
y <- 5*x_1 + 10*x_2 + error
```

I then order the data using the following procedure:

```
XB <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
    XB[[i]] <- 5*x_1[,i] + 10*x_2[,i]
}

vaar <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
    vaar[[i]] <- sqrt(var(XB[[i]]))
}

tau_1 <- list()
tau_2 <- list()
tau_3 <- list()

for (i in 1:100){
    tau_1[[i]] <- qnorm(.1, mean = mean(XB[[i]]), sd = vaar[[i]] + 1)
    tau_2[[i]] <- qnorm(.5, mean = mean(XB[[i]]), sd = vaar[[i]] + 1)
    tau_3[[i]] <- qnorm(.9, mean = mean(XB[[i]]), sd = vaar[[i]] + 1)
}

y_star <- matrix(0, ncol=ncol(y), nrow = nrow(y))
for (i in 1:100){
    for (j in 1:500){
        if(y[j,i] < tau_1[[1]]){
            y_star[j,i] <- 1
        }
        else if(y[j,i] >= tau_1[[1]] & y[j,i] < tau_2[[i]]){
            y_star[j,i] <- 2
        }
        else if(y[j,i] >= tau_2[[i]] & y[j,i] < tau_2[[i]]){
            y_star[j,i] <- 3
        }   
        else{
            y_star[j,i] <- 4
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I try to estimate using this procedure:

```
betas_oprob <- list()
for (j in 1:100){
    betas_oprob[[j]] <- polr(as.ordered(y_star[,j]) ~ 1+x_1[,j] + x_2[,j], method = "probit", Hess=TRUE)
}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure from where to start the polr(.) function. After the first iteration, I get this error message:

```
Error in polr(as.ordered(y_star[, j]) ~ 1 + x_1[, j] + x_2[, j], method = "probit",  
: attempt to find suitable starting values failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
3: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

From where should I start the estimation? I'm sure my method of analysis isn't optimized. I'm just learning R now.